# With SQL I want to find a date BETWEEN 2 columns with LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm working on a site that uses MySQL and in the `reminders` table i have 3 columns called `date`, `date_to`, and `yearly`. The dates are stored as for example 2022-06-15.

If for example there is a `yearly = 1` reminder with `date` and `date_to` being 2021-06-14 and 2021-06-16, how can i look BETWEEN `date` and `date_to` if I need to use LIKE because sometimes i need to use the `-06-15` part because it's `yearly = 1`?

I need to use `-06-15` sometimes because if its a yearly reminder, i cant just check on the year too because its meant to be repeated every year.

Table example:

```
| date       | date_to        | yearly |
| -----------| -------------- | ------ |
| 2021-06-14 | 2021-06-16     | 1      |
| 2022-05-03 | 2022-05-04     | 0      |
```

Expected output after searching for a yearly reminder for date 06-15:

```
| date       | date_to        | yearly |
| -----------| -------------- | ------ |
| 2021-06-14 | 2021-06-16     | 1      |
```

Comment: You should avoid using LIKE and use date functions instead. LIKE is slow and designed for varchars, not for dates. Please make more clear what exactly you want to do by providing sample input and expected outcome.

Comment: Please add sample input table data, and then show the expected table output.

Comment: Edited my question of table data and expected output.

Comment: If I were you I would store TT, MM and (nullable) YYYY in separate columns

Comment: I cant really do that because of a few reasons that i cant explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you just want to check if your date is between a from date and a to_date of your table. This can basically be done with this query:

```
SELECT date_from, date_to, yearly 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE '2021-06-15' BETWEEN date_from AND date_to;
```

If you don't care about the year, but want to check the day only, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` like this:

```
SELECT date_from, date_to, yearly 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT('2021-06-15', "%m-%d") 
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(date_from, "%m-%d") 
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_to, "%m-%d")
```

Then it doesn't matter which year appears (in this example, 2021), only the day will be checked.

It could also be mentioned that MYSQL also provides a function `DAYOFYEAR` which will work correctly in most cases for a query like this:

```
SELECT date_from, date_to, yearly
FROM yourtable
WHERE DAYOFYEAR('2021-06-15') 
BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(date_from) AND DAYOFYEAR(date_to);
```

This will also ignore the year and check the day only. It's a bit easier to read, but it's less safe because it could fail when a lag year is involved since then the day of year will be one more than in other years.

Please note I changed the name of "your" column "date" to "date_from" in my answer. This is no mistake, but I recommend to do not use SQL key words or function names as table name or column name. Furthermore, the column name "date_from" better points out the difference to the column "date_to", so you should rename the column if possible.